# What does the automatic login option do?

Tags: users, auto-login

Under "User Accounts", there's a toggle option labeled **Automatic Login**:

[image: screenshot]

#### What does that do if it's tabbed to "on"?

*I haven't tried the function yet and I'd like advice from an expert.*

Comment: Well... It does what it says. It logs you in automatically on the login screen. What is it you don't understand from that? Please *edit* your question to add this.

Comment: @gertvdijk That's not what it does. Once you get to the login screen (say, by logging out), it's still fully functional, and will not *automatically* log anyone in again (until you reboot or restart the display manager). This is a reasonable question, and many users are reasonably uncomfortable experimenting with administrative settings to find out exactly what they do (for example, many people have just one computer and use it every day for their work). I don't see what's wrong with this question.

Answer (score 13):

"Automatic Login" Inside of each User's options on the User Accounts dialog (remember that you can have several users in the same computer), just means that the user won't be prompted for his/her user password in order to start his/her session.

[image]

You can have only one "Automatic Login" even if this seems to appear in each user. But even if you allow a user to boot without authenticating (signing in), the user may need to unlock his/her keyring for administrative purposes and will always be in need to authenticate each time he/she's in need to run a command with sudo or gksudo from a terminal.

If you need further information don't hesitate to drop a comment in order to continue the support and edit this answer if needed.

As mentioned by @Eliah Kagan in a comment to this answer:

> If you log out to get to the login screen, and want to log back in,
>   you still need to enter a password, even if automatic login is
>   enabled. This is the case on every Ubuntu system on which I've ever
>   used automatic login (which includes 13.04).

Comment: Any idea what config file or setting on system this option actually changes to enable automatic login?

Comment: @Flint I am sorry, I think I couldn't understand what you ask in your comment. Do you mind to try again? Sorry.

Comment: It's okay. I've found the answer to what I was asking. The automatic login option in the picture above adds `autologin-user` line in /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

Answer (score 5):

the automatic log in means that the user will be logged in automatically and wont have to enter password and username at the log in screen.

That's it.