# How can I disable password prompts in Ubuntu

Tags: password, prompt

My wifes computer running Windows 10 became unusable. Could not repair Windows and didn't want to re-install because she was afraid we would lose her pictures. I was able to retrieve her pictures by burning  Ubuntu 20.04 to a CD, and running that. Decided to go ahead and install Ubuntu which wiped Windows out.
How can I disable password prompts in Ubuntu. Really aggravating the amount of prompts that are required just to use the machine.
As I am not familiar with Ubuntu, please hold my hand and explain step by step how to do that. Thank you for your time.

Tom2087

---

Thank you to all that have answered. After I find the %admin line, it will not allow me to edit any data. I appreciate your time.

Comment: What you are asking seems vague: Login password? Sudo password? Keyring password? It's also unwise -- Ubuntu is designed to use some security measures. You can disable some, but not all. Ubuntu is not a Windows clone -- it's quite different, and cannot be made to behave like Windows behaves. If your spouse really prefers to use Ubuntu, she won't mind the occasional password prompt. If your spouse really prefers that you restore Windows, then do so.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Your question needs additional information. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1363558/edit) and add the information asked in the above (and any other) comment(s). Ubuntu is not Windows. You may have heard that Ubuntu is more secure. One of the reasons it is more secure is because of its admin policies that includes asking for the password.

Comment: Take a look at [What does the automatic login option do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316084/what-does-the-automatic-login-option-do)

Comment: Please list some situations where you have to enter a password. You should not have lots of password prompts in Ubuntu, so we need to understand when/where these password prompts happen, and we can suggest a solution for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal window from using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> then:

```
sudo visudo
```

type your password, then find the line that says:

```
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

and change it to `%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`
then save and exit the file.
if you are using nano you can save using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit.

Comment: @Tom2087, I suggest you NOT follow igosad's answer above, although it is well written. You should not have lots of password prompts in Ubuntu, so figure out what the original problem is. This answer disables the "admin" passwords (usually used to make system changes using the command line terminal). I don't think you need to do this, based on the description of your situation.